# rails 3 multiple language for any user

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-i18n

I want my app has multiple languages. To do this, I read [railscasts #138](http://railscasts.com/episodes/138-i18n?view=asciicast)

But there, the writer put a language column to User model and thus users can see pages only in their language as I understand right. But I want my website can be seen in any language by any user just like usual.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved. I added to `controllers/application_controller.rb` this:

```
before_filter :set_locale
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end

private

def default_url_options(options={})
  logger.debug "default_url_options is passed options: #{options.inspect}\n"
  { :locale => I18n.locale }
end
```

Then I added this to `views/layouts/_header.html.erb`:

```
<li><% if I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale %>
      <%= link_to "Türkçe", :locale=>'tr'%>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to "English", :locale=>'en'%>
    <%end%></li>
```

Then to `config/routes.rb` this:

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|tr/ do   # at the beginning
  match '/home' , to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/help' ,  to: 'static_pages#help'

  match '/about' ,  to: 'static_pages#about'
  .....
end
```

Thats it!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this great [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

Comment: Thank you for reply :) Actually I read 1/3 of it and then realized I am not understanding most of it. I have 2 days to translate my website. It is now English. I mean, I don't think I have enough time to deeply understand this guide. Can you just tell me the exact way of question if you know?

Answer (score 0):

in addition to @Pierre-Louis answer, you can look at [globalize3 gem](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3)

Comment: Thank you too :) I skimmed this gem through [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/338-globalize3) and it seemed to me is designed to change database based values' languages. Am I misunderstood it? If the answer is in there somewhere, I will look at it.

Comment: this gem has methods to create some additional db migrations based on what model's attributes (fields in db) need to be translated… you need to store translations somewhere - right? so you have to modify db. and rails cast you mentioned can help you a lot to understand how todo it.

Comment: I realized that I don't need to change the data from database to multiple languages. I just need to translate website pages. Thank you anyway

Comment: than you have to use `t('page.translated_snippet')` syntax in `html.erb` files with `your-locale.yml` definition inside `config` folder

Comment: note, that you asked question, you have received some direct answers and even if you realized that you wanted to ask something else, we spent our time for you, so it would be nice to accept one of our answers...

Comment: I don't want to ask something else. I never mentioned to change database information. Actually I solved my problem now, but none of your answers is the right answer for my question. If I accept them, this would lead other people to misdirections. I am very thankful for your efforts. I wish I knew a way to send you my answer and then you change yours with that and I accept. Do you know any?

Comment: I answered myself. If you copy this answer in 1 hour, I will accept it from yours, if you won't I will accept my own answer. I hope you see this

Comment: `I just need to translate website pages…` your answer not includes solution for this, to be honest… you just solved how to display language switcher with correct routes handling... never mind. glad you found the solution you searched

Comment: The `railscasts` link which I gave in the question and my answer together is the solution itself. `But there, the writer put a language column to User model and thus users can see pages only in their language as I understand right. But I want my website can be seen in any language by any user just like usual.` I asked this and I think you may misunderstood the question.